# Starting Odoo server on macOS using Pycharm fails

Tags: postgresql, pycharm, odoo

I encountered a perplexing bug when attempting to launch Odoo version (v15) on my trusty MacBook Pro M1. As I eagerly anticipated unleashing the power of Odoo, an unforeseen challenge disrupted my progress. The details of this baffling bug are as follows

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e42jU.png)

I was trying to start odoo (v15) server on macos.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

After severals hours of searching, I found the following solution.[solution to the above question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfqGK.png)

You can follow this link for further explanations.
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/79112

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).